How to update existing items during Spring batch migration?
For migration documents between different MongoDB collections, I read items via MongoCursorItemReader based on a filter and then write these data using ItemWriter as shown below. In order to prevent duplicate key error, I remove the items based on the same filter (query).
@Override
public void write(Chunk<? extends Document> chunk) {
    final List<ObjectId> ids = chunk.getItems().stream()
            .map(document -> document.getObjectId("_id"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    final Query deleteQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").in(ids));
    mongoTemplate.remove(deleteQuery, collectionName);

    mongoTemplate.insert(chunk.getItems(), collectionName);
    totalWrittenItems += chunk.size();
}

It works perfectly if the amount of read items is less than batch size. If not, let's sat batch size is 1000 and there are 1500 filtered items, then first it deletes all 1500 records and insert 1000 records. Then, after reading the next batch (last 500 records), it deletes the first inserted 100 records as they are also matches the query and just insert the last batch (500 records inserted in total instead of 1500).
What would be a proper solution (e.g. sing a tasklet for deletion before reading items) for this problem?

Rather than deleting before inserting, I suggest you use MongoTemplate's upsert() or findAndModify() methods.

upsert() is a combination of insert and update (inSERT + UPdate = upsert). If no document is found that matches the query, a new document is created otherwise it updates the document.
findAndModify() can update a document and return either the old or newly updated document in a single operation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html

I have checked both options and even if they have some advantages, it seems to be not suitable for batch operations due to performance considerations. As far as I see from the documentations, "The findAndModify command updates and returns a single document." and that means we need to loop for each item. Is there a proper implementation for bulk operation using the query above?
